# failed to upgrade a pip version from branch

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5

My staging setup uses [ingenious](https://github.com/UCL-INGI/INGInious/) as a pip
my upgrade tool is

```
sudo pip3.5 install git+https://github.com/my_fork/INGInious.git@my_branch --upgrade --no-cache-dir
```

I've noticed that some files get upgraded and some don't

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  155 Jul 10 19:14 agent
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   59 Jul 10 19:14 backend
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  126 Jul 10 19:14 client
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Jul 10 19:14 common
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root   78 Jul 10 19:14 frontend
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  318 Jul 10 19:14 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   36 Jul 10 19:14 __pycache__
```

but a file that was definitely changed and pushed did not get updated

```
cd /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/inginious
ll frontend/webapp/plugins/matrix/admin.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3892 Feb 22 21:08 frontend/webapp/plugins/matrix/admin.htm
```

what can be the cause ??

Comment: Are you missing a space? `@my_branch--upgrade` vs `@my_branch --upgrade`

Comment: just in the question. fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.html files are files that are not copied by default. There are more than one way to include them in the pip distribution, and the one used by INGInious is a MANIFEST.in file.

https://github.com/UCL-INGI/INGInious/blob/master/MANIFEST.in

Simply add the line `recursive-include inginious/frontend/webapp/plugins/matrix *` at the end of the file and setup.py will include the files (not only the .html one; this particular line includes any other files that are not .py files in this directory).

See https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute for more documentation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the file that you are talking about is an html file it is likely that it is not invoked by the python package in files setup.py and requires.txt.  While pip cares about the version of python files within a package it only worries about them if they are listed as a part of that package, ancillary files that are not specifically listed as a part of the data section of setup.py will normally be left alone.

Since you are obviously working on a development branch of your own I would suggest uninstalling and then `cd` to your/a git clone then use: `pip3 install -e .` this will create a soft link between your clone directory and the normal library location.

I wouls also look at using `venv` for this sort of work especially when you are checking that `pip install` gets everything that it should.

Comment: what do you recommend to do ? `pip uninstall` completely and then re install?

Comment: Since you are testing your own branch I would suggest uninstalling and then cd to your/a git clone then use: `pip3 install -e .` this will create a soft link between your clone directory and the normal library location. Also look at using `venv` for this sort of work.

Comment: Hey @steve , sorry for approving your response before checking. your solution didn't work from me. it created a soft link but my app didn't properly identified the pip. is there a way to change the setup.py to instruct the pip installation to copy all the files ? that would make things much simpler